# Django- Update Model objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've a model:-

```
class Model(models.Model):
    a = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Upon firing the `all` query:-

```
objs = Model.objects.all().order_by('time')
```

I need to update the object at the `nth` index. N can be anything.

```
obj[0].a = True
obj[0].save()
```

But the value does not updates. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def set_nth_a_true(n, queryset):
   obj_ = queryset[n]
   obj_.a = True
   obj_.save()


objs = Model.objects.all().order_by('time')
set_nth_a_true(3, objs)
```

this should work, I tested it

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast i dont see any except for `obj[0]` instead of `objs[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
objs = Model.objects.all()
objs[0].a = True  # Queries the database
objs[0].save()  # And again queries db before save
```

More info why it's happening in docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#when-querysets-are-not-cached

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and I can confirm that "issue" is related to the QuerySets behavior. If you need to update your object(s) you have to store them as a separate Model object like :

```
objs = Model.objects.all().order_by('time')
to_update = objs[0]
to_update.a = True
to_update.save()
```